# Change type for input id dynamically from external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html

my `page.php` contains `div id="container"` with `id="input"` which default type is `input type="text"`:

```
    <div class="container">  
        <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-75"> 
                <div id="container">
                    <input type="text" id="input" value="" name="password">
                </div>    
                <input type="submit" value="OK" id="logBtn">  
           </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
```

I want to change `input type="text"` to `input type="password"` for same input `id="input"` with receiving of value `textToPassType(1)`:

```
function textToPassType(val1){
  if (val1 == 1){
     document.getElementById('input').type = 'password';
  } else if (val1 == 0){
     document.getElementById('input').type = 'text';
  }
}
```

This way works only if I call this function included to `page.php`, but if use it in external document: `<script type="text/javascript" src="myjs.js"></script>` method does not works. So, I'm looking for some correct method to change input type dynamically and keep same id name from external `myjs.js` to my `page.php`

Comment: Code works fine. So what are you doing wrong? How are you calling `textToPassType`

Comment: @epascarello  Hello, I'm just calling it from one of if statement conditions, which console it true during typing to the same text-box  `textToPassType(1);`, but it does not changes text to password, even if I call this function with load

Comment: well I ran the code in a snipplet and it ran on chrome.

Comment: @ epascarello yes, I see. and I can't find out what is wrong here, I have removed all css and focus caret function, but same result

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/boqwgste/ runs fine for me

Comment: @epascarello Yes, works successfully if included to  `page.php`, but sorry, I've missed main point, please check my edit, because I want change it from  external `myjs.js` in `page.php`

Comment: well sounds like you are not including the external document correctly.

Comment: @epascarello well all other code works correctly with same 'input' variable `<script type="text/javascript" src="myjs.js"></script>`

Comment: With the information provided it is impossible to help. Inspect the file, make sure the code is in it. Look at the console for errors. Add debug statements to make sure things are called.

Answer (score 1):

[`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) is a keyword in JavaScript, used to declare a variable, you can't use it as a variable name, try naming your variable `val` or something:

```js
function textToPassType(val) {
  if (val == 1) {
    document.getElementById('input').type = 'password';
  } else if (val == 0) {
    document.getElementById('input').type = 'text';
  }
}

textToPassType(1);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-75">
      <div id="container">
        <input type="text" id="input" value="" name="password">
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="OK" id="logBtn">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, It was a typo with var, failure caused by something else, because I've missed main point, sorry for that, please check my edit, because I want change it from external `myjs.js` in `page.php`